# Identifying number of columns in table Html to XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo

Am trying to convert html to pdf using XSl FO. In my html, there are mutiple tables with different columns, so in the xslt I would need to identify the columns of a table from the number of td . Can someone suggest a way to look at the maximum number of 'td' in all the rows to generate those number of fo:table-columns for each table.